# Comparing times in a list and to give the time between instances

Tags: python, list, time, compare

I have a log that outputs the time stamps for time of boot. I want to compare the time between each boot in to mins and seconds.

Here is the format of the list below.

- 16:18:17.10
- 16:20:31.48 = 2 mins 14.38 seconds <-- This what i want
  the output to show.
- 16:27:52.06 = 3 mins 20.18 seconds <-- This what i want
  the output to show.
- 16:33:33.06
- 16:35:50.94

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Thanks @smallwat3r

the finished code is

```
def split_format(var1, var2):
     hour = int(var1.split(':')[0]) - int(var2.split(':')[0])
     minute = int(var1.split(':')[1]) - int(var2.split(':')[1])
     seconds = float(var1.split (':')[2]) - float(var2.split(':')[2])

time = '{} hours {} minutes {} seconds'.format(
    hour, minute, round(seconds, 2)
)

return time



def getFile(): 
prose = str(input('Please enter the file path for your text file: '))

dictionary = {}

infile = open(prose, 'r')
line_num = 1
line_num2 = 2
for line in infile:
    dictionary[line_num]=line
    line_num += 1
    line_num2 += 1

base = 1
base2 = 2
for x in dictionary:
    print(dictionary[base2],(split_format(dictionary[base2],dictionary[base])))
    base += 1
    base2 += 1


infile.close()

getFile()
```

Comment: Please see [mcve]. How are these being logged? How are you reading them?

Comment: You have not asked any question; this is just a series of statements. In addition to the MCVE, please show what you've tried and also see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The log is a simple bat file that echos %date% %time% out to network location. I'm investigating a boot hang issue in Citrix pvs. Is it possible I python to compare two times and repeat the process through the list?

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing or tutorial service; if you have a problem with your implementation then please ask about that, otherwise you will need to do some research and write some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the below which returns `0 hours 2 minutes 14.38 seconds`

```
time1 = '16:18:17.10'
time2 = '16:20:31.48'

def split_format(var1, var2):
    hour = int(var1.split(':')[0]) - int(var2.split(':')[0])
    minute = int(var1.split(':')[1]) - int(var2.split(':')[1])    
    seconds = float(var1.split (':')[2]) - float(var2.split(':')[2])
    time = '{} hours {} minutes {} seconds'.format(
        hour, minute, round(seconds, 2)
    )
    return time

print(split_format(time2, time1))
```